# LuaTeX compiling

Tags: macros, luatex, plain-tex, lua

May someone can explain me how to compile the LuaTeX source files available here :
http://michel.quercia.free.fr/cours-MP.tgz
together with the macro's files
http://michel.quercia.free.fr/montchapet.tgz

On Fedora, I type `lualatex cours-MP.tex` and here is the log :

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./cours-MP.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-04-06> (./cours.tex (./montchapet.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.280 {\let\@tmp\rm\xdef\rm{\@tmp
                               \def\noexpand\euro{{\noexpand\eurofont@rm e}}}
```

EDIT: an other server to get the files:

https://rpidejr.zapto.org/f/6346ef88c8194da1b1aa/
https://rpidejr.zapto.org/f/28b2a6641ae643cdb01d/

Comment: Oh ok, I download the file on my own server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document is written in PlainTeX, not LaTeX. (How can you tell? The fact that the driver file `cours-MP.tex` uses `\eject` and `\bye` and does *not* use `\documentclass` should be a dead giveaway.) Hence, you must use `luatex` rather than `lualatex` to compile the file.

Incidentally, on line 267 in the sub-file `variable-réelle.tex`, one should change `=\limits^{\text{def}}` to `\mathop{=}\limits^{\text{def}}` in order to make the code compilable under the current version of LuaTeX. (For TeXLive2021, that's version 1.13.0.)

**Aside**: As @HenriMenke has pointed out in the comment section, `=\limits` used to be syntactically legal thru version 0.78 of LuaTeX, distributed with TL2014. (AFAICT, `=\limits` was never syntactically legal with any version of pdfTeX.) The files provided in the OP's link are all date-stamped 2014 and 2015; this would explain why Michel Quercia was able to get away with writing `=\limits`. As @HenriMenke further points out, the best fix actually consists of replacing

```
=\limits^{\text{def}}
```

with

```
\mathrel{\mathop{=}\limits^{\text{def}}}
```

as `=` is (mostly? always?) a relational operator.

Do be prepared for the first compilation run to require two or more minutes to complete, as the document uses the raster font `Concrete Roman`. This requires the system to generate lots and lots of gf and pk font files the first time the document is compiled. Any subsequent compilation runs should be much faster.

Comment: `=\limits` used to work in some old version of LuaTeX. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19765435#19765435

Comment: @HenriMenke - Very interesting. Indeed, the files mentioned by the OP are all dated 2015 and earlier. When I wrote the answer above, I suspected that `=\limits` must have been valid at some point in the past, especially as `=\limits` was the *only* passage that didn't pass must under LuaTeX 1.13.0. (As I do 99.9% of my own writing in LaTeX, not PlainTeX, I'm definitely not an authority on what may and may not have been valid, syntactically speaking, in some distant-past versions of Plain-LuaTeX.)

Comment: The last version that had this bug was LuaTeX beta-0.78 in TL2014 (I believe). Updating the source files is a very reasonable recommendation, but I think it should read `\mathrel{\mathop{=}\limits^{\text{def}}}` (although the visual difference will be minuscule).

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks! I've gone ahead and inserted a whole new paragraph in the answer, as the points you've raised deserve to be brought to the fore prominently.